# Web front-end for directory servers (LDAP) similar to phpMySQLAdmin?

Tags: ldap, directory

Is there some web front-end to administer LDAP servers, in a similar way as you can use phpMySQLAdmin to administer DBs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean [phpLDAPAdmin](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a web front-end, but I like [Softerra's LDAP browser](http://www.ldapbrowser.com/).  It comes in free and paid-for versions, although I've only ever needed the free one.

What kind of LDAP are you trying to manage - OpenLDAP, eDirectory, something more exotic?  If there's a management tool that the vendor provides with it, you may be better off using that.